# native gzip decompression in chrome in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible in chrome to decompress a file and read the content in js in a native way, Not via javascript itself. I need to decompress a big file in the browser and doing this in javascript is really buggy and slow. I know it is possible to deliver gzipped html and css files to the browsers. is it possible to do the same with files that are loaded into javascript via ajax?

Comment: This should happen automatically if it's configured properly on server side, no?

Comment: How are you requesting this file?  AJAX requests should be auto-decompressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to do the same with files that are loaded into javascript via ajax?

Yes, ajax requests are treated like every other HTTP requests and the responses will be decompressed automatically. You just have to send the same appropriate `Content-Encoding` headers.