# No auto-decompression of gzipped json on browser's side when using angular's http get method

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, gzip

I'm trying to load a json file using angular (v1.2.6):

```
$http.get('myfile.json').success(function(data) { ... }
```

This works fine, except when I create a (static) compressed version of the file on the server, and try to load 'myfile.json.gz' instead (to reduce the loading time).

The request headers seem correct (Chrome 31.0 on Mac) (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390343/can-you-gunzip-the-contents-of-a-get-request-in-angular) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8350800/1673408)):

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
```

while the response headers contain:

```
Connection: close
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 702468
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

However, the content is not automatically decompressed by the client browser, as I understand [it should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556275/native-gzip-decompression-in-chrome-in-javascript). `data.length` is ~700Kb instead of the original uncompressed ~3Mb.

Although this one [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/HrDrzifKKQg) suggests it needs to be done manually, I understand decompression should be automatic and transparent.

My question is, should it be decompressed automatically? and why isn't it the case here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your content type should not be "*application/x-gzip** it should stay :
**application/json**

The content encoding is enough to say to the browser that the content is zipped.

What HTTP server are you running ?
You should configure it in order to return the correct mime type, regardless of the .gz extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction, I managed to make it work.
My production server is a modified Apache, on which I have no control. It allows for a limited configuration using `.htaccess` files, and adding:
`AddEncoding gzip .jsongz
AddType application/json .jsongz`
in the right folder does the trick (complex extensions like `.json.gz` are not supported, hence this custom `.jsongz`).
If you can use `RewriteRules`, a cleaner configuration is possible, which will automatically send the compressed version when clients support it.