# AngularJS HTTP$ Response gzipped

Tags: angularjs, http, azure, gzip, httpresponse

I have a website that works fine on localhost but doesn't on its production Mircosoft Azure cloud website. I have tracked the issue to the http$ call getting a response that is encoded (gzip), following are the headers:

Request:

```
GET http://npotix.azurewebsites.net/clientViews/vwEvent.html HTTP/1.1
Referer: http://npotix.azurewebsites.net/default.html#/event/1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1
Host: npotix.azurewebsites.net
Cookie: ARRAffinity=26725901b3d032fb3e05187b909a72435484b56213bec82159ec5ec09006c4d2
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 770
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Sat, 13 Sep 2014 20:23:46 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "075979e90cfcf1:0"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Data, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS
Date: Fri, 03 Oct 2014 14:11:17 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Age: 0
```

What is the best/easiest way to handle this gzip response to my Angularjs/http$ GET call?

I can supply code, but since this is a 'general' what-is-best type question I don't know that it is necessary; please let me know if it will help.

Also, as I understand it you can't turn off encoding on Mircosoft Azure cloud websites, so that is not an option.

Thanks for any help in advance!

**EDIT -** Ok, it now seems like it is NOT that the server is sending back a gzipped response. What I think I am seeing is that the database connection is not working; my website on the azure server can't reach the database whereas the website run in debug locally can.

Anyone run into this?!

Thanks.

Comment: The browser should already take care of decompressing the result, transparent to AngularJS -- are you sure you've interpreted your clues correctly?

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859246/no-auto-decompression-of-gzipped-json-on-browsers-side-when-using-angulars-htt)?

Comment: Rytmis - that is what I thought, but it isn't working. Well, as I said, it works on localhost but not on the Azure website host. The response is a dataset cast to json and as you can see the Content-Encoding: gzip. When I use Fiddler2 the button shows up stating the response is encoded and do I want to transform it. When I do this then the raw response is what I would expect. Why the browser isn't doing this I don't know.

Comment: Blaze - I see that question, but it answers for Apache .htaccess and I don't know enough to translate that to Azure cloud hosting. there might be a solution on the Azure IIS side of things, but as I stated as far as I know I can't alter how Azure sends its responses. Again it works locally, just not on Azure. Surely someone else has run into this.